# Passing the HTML table to JSON via Server side causing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, ajax, json

I've a dynamically created HTML table in the Server side code(using C#). When i pass that to client site using JASON. I couldn't able to receive that code in the client site. this is my code in the Server Side.

```
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ExcelUpload.asmx/UploadFile",
            data: JSON.stringify({ XML: XMLDoc}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#Status").html("<br><center><img src='ajax-loader.gif'/></center>");

            },
            success: function (result) {
                var output = "";
                var re = eval('(' + result.d + ')');
                if (re.length > 0) {
                    for (var i in re) {
                        var xl = re[i];
                        switch (parseInt(xl.status)) {
                            case 1: { output = xl.message; break; }
                            case 2: { output = xl.message; break; }
                        }
                    }
                    $("#Status").html(output);
                }
            },

            error: function (result) {
                $("#Status").addClass("error");
                $("#Status").html(result.d);
            }

        });
```

In that server side code I'm generating the HTML table using this code

```
    HTML += "<table id='excelDoc'>";
        HTML += "<tr><th>Date</th><th>Description</th><th>Reference</th><th>Nominal Code</th><th>Dept Code</th><th>Debit</th><th>Credit</th></tr>";
        HTML += "<tr><td>" + eDoc.posting_Date.ToShortDateString() + "</td><td>" + eDoc.Description + "</td><td>" + eDoc.Ref_Number + "</td><td></td><td></td><td class='db'></td><td class='cr'></td></tr>";
```

HTML += "";

status = "{status : 1 , message : " + HTML  + "}";
return  " ["+ status+ "]";

Please Help me.

Comment: whats the error ? Or you do not have any error and you just recieve empty result in successcalback

Comment: Hi anand thank for your reply. it shows the result set is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

why are you doing **result.d** ?
Should it not be simply **result** ?
1 thing I notice more, in your AJAX request, your
`dataType: "json"` 
but you are returning a simple string. Change to
`dataType:"text"` 
and then try returning the string. It would def work